# How do I form a superlative like this?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, superlatives

Is "My prefecture have most rainy days in Japan" right?

I mean to say that "The prefecture that I live in is almost every day rainy. There are no other prefecture such a rainy ....."

Answer (score 1):

> My prefecture **has** the most rainy days in Japan.

Would be a perfectly understandable way of saying **no other prefecture has more days that rain** than yours.  **Prefecture** is singular and so needs a corresponding verb of the same number, **has**.
You could also say:

> My prefecture **has more** rainy days during the year **than any other** prefecture.